# Android "couldn't log to binary event log: overflow"

Tags: android, binary, overflow, android-4.4-kitkat

I have an android app that has been running without problems until I updated my device to android 4.4 (kitkat).
Now I start getting this error and some part of the program is broken with this in the log cat_

> Android "couldn't log to binary event log: overflow"

Does anyone have any idea what is happening?

Comment: Did you solve this?  Obviously it is spamming the log because something is unhappy, but did you narrow it down to graphics, sound, something else?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you know this but 4.4 has some issues.
In order for it to work you will have to change your project's target SDK to 4.4 KitKat or if you haven't installed the version yet go into android manager and get the appropriate files.
Even then your app may not work, if it doesn't, downgrade your device to android 4.3 or whatever version your app was working at.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help, but I was having this same issue. I was using Butterknife and not declaring the id on the @OnClick. After setting it, it worked and logged perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

clue：

in 4.4.4 r1

/frameworks/native/services/surfaceflinger/EventLog/EventLog.cpp

```
58void EventLog::TagBuffer::log() {
59    if (mOverflow) {
60        ALOGW("couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.");
...
67}
```

That should be the problem

mOverflow = ture 's case :
e.g:

```
116void EventLog::TagBuffer::writeString8(const String8& value) {
...
118    const int32_t stringLen = value.length();
119    const size_t needed = 1 + sizeof(int32_t) + stringLen;
120    if (mPos + needed > STORAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
121        mOverflow = true;
122        return;
...
128}
```

STORAGE_MAX_SIZE = 128
your tag's text > char[128]

I think it is due to the shortage of hardware resources of the old equipment

New systems often require more memory space

Maybe it's the system ROM 's problem

or try curtail your TAG's lenth.
or mabye is not your APP's ErrorLog